# Let {$r_n$} be an enumeration of all rationals in [0, 1]. Show that {$r_n$} is not convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let {$r_n$} be an enumeration of all rationals in [0, 1]. Show that {$r_n$} is not convergent.

My approach
Let $r_n$ be the sequence.It can't be monotone . Thus there exists monotonic subsequnces (both increasing and decreasing) in it.Also it is bounded.
Thus it has two limit points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: But all the rationals in [0,1] are not in the a_n defined @Koro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the sequence does converge to some limit $\ell$.  Choose $\epsilon>0$ so that at least one of $\ell-\epsilon>0$ and $\ell+\epsilon<1$ holds.

Then there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$, we must have $r_n\in(\ell-\epsilon,\ell+\epsilon)$.  However, this in turn implies that all the rational numbers in $[0,\ell-\epsilon]$ (or $[\ell+\epsilon,1]$, depending on the above) must be enumerated by $r_1,\ldots,r_N$.  However, there are clearly infinitely many such rationals, so this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on the contrary that the given sequence is convergent (i.e., $\limsup r_n =\liminf r_n$). Consider subsequences defined by $a_n=\frac 1{n}, b_n=\frac n{n+1}$ and note that $a_n\to 0, b_n\to 1$, which is a contradiction as $\limsup r_n \ne \liminf r_n $.